# The eigendecomposition by complex integration

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Let $M_{n}$ denote the set of all $n\times n$-matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ and let us consider that $M_n$ is equipped with the Hilbert-Schmidt norm. Then we may identify $M_n\cong\mathbb{C^{n^2}}$. For any $A\in M_{n}$ we choose the distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ of $A$ with the eigenvectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and a circle $S=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=r\}$, where $r>0$, not meeting all of $\lambda_i$'s. Then we can define the matrix $Q\in M_{n}$ by
$$Q= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_S (zI-A)^{-1}dz.$$
(Note that the right-hand side means a contour integration of the matrix-valued function $z\mapsto (zI-A)^{-1}\in M_{n}(\cong \mathbb{C}^{n^2})$ defined on $S$, where the $I$ is the identity matrix, and that the matrix $zI-A$ is nonsingular for all $z\in S$). Then I would like to show the following properties:

1. $QA=AQ$.
2. $QQ=Q$.

If they are proved then we have, by the $(1)$, a decomposition $V=QV\oplus (I-Q)V$, where $V$ is the vector space $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Moreover, since both of the subspaces $V_+=QV$ and $V_-=(I-Q)V$ are invariant for the linear transformation $A$ defined on $V$ by the (2), $A$ can be decomposed by the formula $A=A_+\oplus A_-$. Then all eigenvalues of $A_+$ reside inside of $S$ and the eigenvalues of $A_-$ does outside of $S$. Iterating this procedure, we have a decomposition $V=V_1\oplus \dots \oplus V_n$ with $V_i$ spanned by the $v_i$, which is the eigendecomposition of a vector space! (I heard that it is precisely a spectral decomposition, but I do not know the operator theory, unfortunately).

**My attempt.** I tried, anyway, the case of $n=2$ (though it is a tentative and concrete try). Suppose that $A$ has the form
$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d
        \end{pmatrix}$$
then
$$(zI-A)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\text{det}(zI-A)}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        z-d & b \\
        c & z-a
        \end{pmatrix}.$$
Since $\text{det}(zI-A)=(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)$, if the eigenvalue lying inside of $S$ is the only $\lambda_1$ then the residue theorem says
$$Q=\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
  \begin{pmatrix}
        \oint_S \frac{z-d}{(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)}dz & \oint_S \frac{b}{(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)}dz  \\
        \oint_S \frac{c}{(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)}dz  & \oint_S \frac{z-a}{(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)}dz 
        \end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}
\begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1-d & b \\
        c & \lambda_1-a
        \end{pmatrix}.$$
Similarly we see that if both of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ lie inside of $S$ then $Q$ is determined by
$$Q=\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
  \begin{pmatrix}
        \oint_S \frac{z-d}{(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)}dz & \oint_S \frac{b}{(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)}dz  \\
        \oint_S \frac{c}{(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)}dz  & \oint_S \frac{z-a}{(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)}dz 
        \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{\lambda_1-d}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}+\frac{\lambda_2-d}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1} & \frac{b}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}+\frac{b}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1} \\
        \frac{c}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}+\frac{c}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1} &\frac{\lambda_1-a}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}+\frac{\lambda_2-a}{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}        \end{pmatrix}
=        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$
It satisfies the commutativity (1) as
$$AQ=\frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1-d & b \\
        c & \lambda_1-a
        \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
        a\lambda_1-ad-cb & b\lambda_1 \\
        c\lambda_1 & d\lambda_1-ad-cd
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$QA=\frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}
\begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1-d & b \\
        c & \lambda_1-a
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d
        \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
        a\lambda_1-ad-cb & b\lambda_1 \\
        c\lambda_1 & d\lambda_1-ad-cd
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Subsequently, to verify the idempotency (2), I calculate
$$QQ=\frac{1}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1-d & b \\
        c & \lambda_1-a
        \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1-d & b \\
        c & \lambda_1-a
        \end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
        (\lambda_1-d)^2+bc & b(\lambda_1-d)+b(\lambda_1-a) \\
        c(\lambda_1-d)+c(\lambda_1-a) & (\lambda_1-a)^2+bc
        \end{pmatrix},
$$
but we have $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=a+d$, from which it follows that $(\lambda_1-d)+(\lambda_1-a) =\lambda_1-\lambda_2$. Additionally, observe from $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=a+d$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2=ad-bc$ that
$$(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(\lambda_1-d)
=\lambda_1^2-d\lambda_1+d\lambda_2-\lambda_1\lambda_2 
=\lambda_1^2+(-2\lambda_1+a+d)d-ad+bc \\
=\lambda_1^2-2d\lambda_1+d^2+bc 
=(\lambda_1-d)^2+bc
$$
and thus we conculude that
$$QQ
=\frac{1}{(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
        (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(\lambda_1-d) & b(\lambda_1-\lambda_2) \\
        c(\lambda_1-\lambda_2) & (\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(\lambda_1-a)
        \end{pmatrix}
=Q.
$$

**My question.** It is difficult that the above way is generalized, I think. How do I prove them for general $n$?

Comment: Comment (i) I think that one way to proceed in this sort of question is to prove it first for diagonalisable matrices, and then use the fact that these are dense in $M_n$. Comment (ii) For the first part , surely the integrand in $Q$ is a polynomial in $z-A$, and so $Q$ itself is a polynomial in $A$ and so commutes with $A$.

Comment: I see! It seems that your idea is good, so I will try it. Thank you!